# Local Beans Definition with Camel RouteTemplates in Springboot

Tags: apache-camel

Camel 4.2.0
Springboot 3.2.0

I have an issue where my camel bean in the TemplateRouteBuilder seems to be ignored and not created or recognised.

```
    return routeTemplate(this.usageName+FunctionStages.PROCESS.toString()+"Template")
            .templateParameter("name")
            .templateParameter("myPeriod", "3s")
            .templateParameter("processBean")
            .from("direct:{{name}}"+FunctionStages.PROCESS.toString())
            .to("bean:{{processBean}}");
```

The following seems to ignore the created class:

```
    TemplatedRouteBuilder.builder(this.getCamelContext(), usageName+FunctionStages.PROCESS.toString()+"Template")
        .parameter("name", this.usageName)
        .parameter("processBean", "processClass")
        .bean("processClass",        ignore ----> new Process0())
        .add();
```

Starting the route seems to error with:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route4 at: >>> To[bean:{{processBean}}] <<< in route: Route(route4)[From[direct:{{name}}Process] -> [To[bean:{{pro... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: bean://processClass due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: processClass
```

Attempting to add the configuration to springboot has no effect as:

```
@Bean
public Process0 processClass(){
    return new  Process0();
}
```

Any suggestion would be most appreciated.
TIA